# "tensor" parameter in tf.unstack

Tags: tensorflow

I'm facing one big problem, I want to use LSTM unit in TensorFlow, so first, I have to transform my input data from "tensor" to sequential "list" with tf.unstack.

But my sequence length is not determined before building up the tensor Graph, which means the value varies along the training iteration.

I can get the length value through tf.shape() or other tensor parameters define. The problem is the length value I got is "tensor" type and "unstack" function

requires "int" inputs!

So, any one any thought? Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like a general setting.
Do you get the input data from another sub-model? then you can trace back to the source of inputs(here just call it as input_fn) and let input_fn outputs the length of original data.